# Smooch Type Activity iOS

Tags: ios, smooch

I'm trying to post a user type activity via the iOS SDK. Any idea?

Updated:
Smooch does not currently support user typing indicators. You can see details of all available features here: https://docs.smooch.io/guide/channel-capabilities/

Comment: What problem are you having, exactly? Right off the bat I'll say that it's not a good idea to try and send appMaker typing indicators from the iOS SDK since it requires you to distribute an app or account scope JWT to the client device, which basically gives each of your users full permissions on your app or account. They can create and manage integrations, webhooks, view conversation history for all users, etc...

Comment: @michaels  The code above is an example from their REST documentation: "Notify Smooch when an app maker starts or stops typing a response.". I was trying to find how to do this with their iOS SDK while consuming their low level APIs. If you're interested you can read through their documentation here - https://docs.smooch.io/api/ios/Protocols/SKTConversationDelegate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smooch: User typing indicators will be added by end of this year for all 3 of our SDKs (Web, iOS, Android)

Answer (score 2):

The typing indicators you were trying to send (https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#typing-activity) only represent the appMaker typing to the appUser.

It's not safe to make this API call from the mobile client because it requires the use of app or account scoped credentials, which you don't want to store on the client for security reasons.

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment I wanted to find our if their iOS SDK supports sending user typing indicator since it supports it on the client side. I realize the appMaker curl was a bad example so I removed it from the question. According to smooch user typing indicators will be added by end of this year for all 3 of our SDKs. Thanks!